# homework: rings, matrices and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory

1. $A,B$ are both $n \times n$ and diagonal matrices. Prove that there is a matrix $X$ which is $n \times n$, and polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that $A= p(X), B= q(X)$
2. Is this true for ANY 2 matrices (we do not assume that they're diagonal anymore)? why? [hint: the difference between the ring of matrices to the ring of polynomials]

I have no direction right now.  thought of $A$ and $B$ as $\displaystyle PDP^{-1}$ format but can't see how it helps. hints, anything? .